# What is it called in English? (the part that closes dumbbell bar weights?)

Tags: word-request

In gyms there are bars or dumbbells, and while putting the weights on the sides of the bar, it's used to close each side of the bar by thing which closes the weights to the bar and avoid it to fall out, and make it more safety for use.

What are they called in English?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific type in your image are called "spring clips" or "spring collars" or "spring clamps". They seem to be generally synonymous. "Spring" comes from the coiled metal section.

[Here's an example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/We-Sports%C2%AE-Dumbbells-Fitness-Equipment/dp/B008QVTA7O) of one being sold on Amazon using all three terms.

There are other types that don't have the spring, and then they are generally called simply barbell "collars", "clamps" or "clips".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that this is the full name (spring collars). But I believe that in the gym the use shortly just in one of them, maybe collars or just springs. I would like to know the acceptable term in gyms.

Comment: Just pick one... your region may determine which is the most common... if you want to fit in, ask someone at the gym what they're called and use that term. Any of the three - "collars", "clamps", or "clips" - should get you what you need.

Comment: In my case we are in non-English country speakers, but we are friends from different countries that the English language only connects between us. No body of us is native English speaker. I hope now the condition is clear. So I definitely need help from native English speakers:)

Comment: You seem to be missing my point. There's no one "right" answer. All three options are viable.

Comment: From your description of the specific circumstances, it sounds like Catija's _"Just pick one"_ advice is all the more valid.  I go to two gyms _in the same city._  People in one call them bar clamps, in the other they call them spring clips.  I use one term in one gym, and the other in the other. Everyone understands each other.